# Constructing a "dumb" lat-long to lat-long conversion in pyproj

Tags: python, pyproj

I have:

```
import pyproj
c = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
c(180, 180)
```

I expect:

```
(180, 180)
```

I get:

```
(1e+30, 1e+30)
```

Why is that?

Comment: Try giving a valid latitude value? -90 <= latitude <= 90

Comment: Ah. Apologies, been a long day.

Comment: No worries; I've been there myself!